# How to set a specific key on wayland?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keymap, wayland

I already set `ctrl:nocaps` through `gnome-tweaks` to avoid pinky injury. However, I still need to have Cap Lock somewhere.

On X11 I usually do

```
printf "keycode  127 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock" > ~/.Xmodmap
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

to map Caps Lock to Break key.

Unfortunately, Xmodmap doesn't work on GNOME 43.1 due to Wayland.

How could I assign Caps Lock to Break key under Wayland?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but there's an option "Both Shift together enable Caps Lock" in gnome-tweaks / Keyboard & Mouse / Additional Layout Options / Compatibility options.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Double shift is even better than Break key. Thank you! Still, it is unfortunate that custom keybindings can't be made on Wayland...